# How can i get rid of "__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__" this error?

Tags: webpack

HI I am currently using webpack 5.35, I am stuck at one error while compiling the code :

here is the error:

server (webpack 5.36.1) compiled with 3 warnings in 934 ms
(node:86704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access '**WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT**' before initialization
at Module.default (webpack://dwords-web/./server/express.js?:4:42)
at eval (webpack://dwords-web/./server/server.js?:13:39)
at Function.**webpack_require**.a (/Users/shikharsrivastava/Desktop/dword/dwords-web/dist/server.generated.js:635:13)
at eval (webpack://dwords-web/./server/server.js?:1:21)
at Object../server/server.js (/Users/shikharsrivastava/Desktop/dword/dwords-web/dist/server.generated.js:184:1)
at **webpack_require** (/Users/shikharsrivastava/Desktop/dword/dwords-web/dist/server.generated.js:570:41)
at /Users/shikharsrivastava/Desktop/dword/dwords-web/dist/server.generated.js:719:37
at Object. (/Users/shikharsrivastava/Desktop/dword/dwords-web/dist/server.generated.js:722:12)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:86704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:86704) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I can't even find the error in which file, please help me out , i did the google but nothing similar to this help me

Comment: show your config

Comment: webpack.config.client.production.js  ------  https://github.com/dwebprotocol/dwords-web/blob/main/webpack.config.client.production.js
webpack.config.client.js   ------   https://github.com/dwebprotocol/dwords-web/blob/main/webpack.config.client.js
webpack.config.server.js --------  https://github.com/dwebprotocol/dwords-web/blob/main/webpack.config.server.js

Comment: here is babelrc

here is babelrc

{
    "presets": [
      ["@babel/preset-env", 
        { 
          "targets": { 
              "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "react-hot-loader/babel"
    ]
  }

Comment: As an experiment change - CURRENT_WORKING_DIR for __dirname

Comment: in which file all the webpack config file?

Comment: No luck still the same issue